# How to choose and wire a Variable Frequency Drive

Tags: vfd

I have a 1.5 HP 3PH 240V Leeson motor that I want to drive my lathe, but I want to vary the speed. I asked a [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/522173/variable-speed-control-of-a-dc-motor) on this site about a month ago about how to do that and the recommendation was a variable frequency drive.  I'd ideally like to buy a used VFD on ebay to save me some cost and wire it myself. A few questions about what VFD to choose:

[image: photo of ratings plate on motor]

1. I only have 110V available, but this motor is 208-230V input. When I asked on this site before, I discovered that some VFDs take 110V 1ph in and double it in the output. I'm thinking that any 110V 1PH input, 3ph 220V output is going to work for me, but confirming.
2. Do I need a VFD that is rated exactly 1.5 HP (same as my motor) or would something rated for more (2HP or 3HP) work?
3. Any other considerations I should be looking for in a VFD?

When I wire it, would a heavy duty extension cord work for the input or should I get something else? What kind of wire would I want between the VFD and the motor?

Comment: ad 1) Never seen such inverter that doubles the voltage, I am a filed engineer more than 20 yrs. Post a link of such example, then maybe I'll start to believe.

Comment: @Marko Buršič https://www.weg.net/catalog/weg/US/en/Drives/Variable-Speed-Drives/Micro-and-Mini-Drives/Variable-Speed-Drive-CFW300/DRIVE-CFW300A06P0S1NB20/p/13059272

Comment: Contrary to what Marko said, I have a 120 in 240 out inverter that I am currently using daily on a 1 HP motor. I think it may be available in 1.5 HP also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'd ideally like to buy a used VFD on ebay to save me some cost and wire it myself.

That is rather risky. I have see VFDs on eBay that I would have recommended to the owner that they pay someone to dispose of it if necessary. It was a model that I once marketed, but so far obsolete and ultimately problematic that it was not something that anyone should buy.

> I'm thinking that any 110V 1PH input, 3ph 220V output is going to work for me, but confirming.

I agree with the advise given previously.

> Do I need a VFD that is rated exactly 1.5 HP (same as my motor) or would something rated for more (2HP or 3HP) work?

You can use a 2 Hp and probably a 3 Hp model. I strongly advise you to buy only a model for which that you can download and read the manual prior to purchase. VFDs generally have adjustments to match the VFD to the motor. Find those adjustments and review the range of adjustment. That will confirm what size motor it is suited for.

> Any other considerations I should be looking for in a VFD?

As mentioned above, get the manual first. Check the quality of the manual and see if it answers any questions about installing and operating it. If there is a readily available, good quality manual, that is at least some indication of a decent product. For industrial use, I would recommend you determine if the brand is sold by a local dealer. For a hobby use, a less expensive brand will probably be ok. You might check hobby forums for brand recommendations.

> When I wire it, would a heavy duty extension cord work for the input or should I get something else? What kind of wire would I want between the VFD and the motor?

A heavy duty extension cord is fine for the input. For the output, you need three current-carrying conductors and a ground. You can get that as a flexible cord, but it may be a bit hard to find. I bought some recently from Amazon and will find the description and add it later. It would be best to put the VFD near the motor. It will be difficult to find a plug and receptacle for that voltage at low current, so consider wiring directly to the motor without a plug.

I bought a short length of 18/4 wire on eBay, not Amazon. The picture below shows what you need in 16/4, but you only need 18. For mechanical durability, and reliable connection to the VFD terminals, I wouldn't use anything smaller than 18 even though smaller would be ok for the current. Because of vibration, I wouldn't use solid wire, but you could wire to a box near the motor with solid wire and put something flexible from the box to the motor.

The voltage doubler VFDs are available only in quite low power ratings. You might not find one for 1.5 Hp. You could probably use a 1 Hp model and limit use of the motor to 1 Hp by VFD adjustments. If you do that, it is possible that higher than expected no-load current could be problematic.

Regarding Input Current

The VFD 120 V input current is likely to be more than 20 amps for a fully loaded 1.5 Hp motor. You can not determine that from the motor current because the VFD compensates for the motor power factor. The **[WEG VFD](https://www.weg.net/catalog/weg/US/en/Drives/Variable-Speed-Drives/Micro-and-Mini-Drives/Variable-Speed-Drive-CFW300/DRIVE-CFW300A06P0S1NB20/p/13059272)** that I looked at has 97% efficiency, but it creates its own low power factor by causing harmonic distortion.

[image]

Comment: #16 is the minimum legal size for AC mains cordage.  Do not use in-wall cables for flexible cord applications.   /4 cordage is readily available by-the-foot at your friendly neighborhood electrical supply in any size you want. Remember in cordage, safety ground IS counted. So you need /4 to drive 3-phase delta.

Comment: You definitely need 12AWG or 10AWG for the input wiring.

Comment: thanks, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bigger problem.  That motor appears to want 5.4 amps at 240V.  3-phase delta.

So `5.4 x 240 x sqrt(3)` is ..... 2244 watts.  That is normal speed and assuming zero conversion loss in the VFD.   Further, VA will be a larger number than watts.

Out of a "110V" outlet as you call it (120V actually), the maximum you can get is 1800 VA... unless it's a 20A circuit and socket and plug, then 2400 VA.

You cannot power this motor off common "110V" sockets.

To go larger, now 120V/30A is not really a thing... It's only used for travel trailers.  The next step up is 240V/15A, which is 3600 VA. This makes a lot more sense for that motor.

You will need to provision 240V to deliver enough power to make use of this motor.  That solves your step-up problem and now you just need a normal VFD.

Comment: I think 1.5 HP is pushing the limit for a 120V outlet. Even a 20 Amp outlet. So I agree with that. But the motor is 80 percent efficient (on the name plate). So the input power is 1.5 HP / 0.8 which is only 1400 Watts. The power factor of the VFD and the power factor of the motor are not the same, but the VFD power factor may be low also. I believe the full=load amps is 4.6, not 5.4. That is what the nameplate says for 60 Hz.

Comment: This is helpful, thanks!

Comment: No, I didn't forget about power factor. I mentioned that the power factor might be low. And I said that 1.5 HP is probably too much for a 120V outlet, even a 20Amp one. That is because of power factor. If the VFD had 1.0 Power Factor then theoretically a 20Amp outlet would be fine. But I have recently been using a 1HP VFD (120 in 240 out) and it actually has a nameplate that says max input current is 24A. So I don't think it is a good idea to use a 1.5 HP VFD with an outlet. It should be hard wired with appropriate wire (probably 10AWG, but check the tables).

Comment: @mkeith Oh, you're right, you did... my bad.